# парсер иногда выдает ошибку bs4

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Новичок. Есть парсер на питоне, заходит на страницу и берет из класса текст. Для отображения ошибки сделал цикл парсинга одной и той же странице (так в базе страниц нужно спарсить около 2000) - при выполнении цикла, иногда он парсит правильно нужный текст, а иногда выводит ошибку. С чем это может быть связано?

весь код приложить не могу в силу того, что сайт нельзя светить
но единственное в коде связанное с list index:

```
stock_product = link.parent.select('td')[1].text
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Иногда сайты могут блокировать или ограничивать IP-адреса, которые слишком часто обращаются к ним